# MYSQL select all record if contains specific number

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv

I have a small problem, I have a table like this:

```
id|name|group|date_created
1|Volvo|1,3|06-04-2020 10:00:00
2|Audi|3|06-04-2020 10:00:00
```

etc....

Now I wish I could get all the records that have the value 1 inside the group column.

I tried LIKE "%1%", but I don't think it's a good query. Can you address me?

```
SELECT id FROM cars WHERE group LIKE '%1%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your query is that it would wrongly match `'1'` against a list like `'45,12,5'` for example.

One method is to add commas on both ends before searching:

```
where concat(',', `group`, ',') like '%,1,%';
```

But in MySQL, it is much more convenient to use [string function `find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), whose purpose is just what you are looking for, ie search for a value in a comma-separated list:

```
select id from cars where find_in_set('1', `group`) > 0
```

Notes:

- you should fix your data model, and have a separated table to store relationship between `id`s and `group`s, with each tuple on a separate row. Related reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)
- `group` is a reserved word in MySQL, so not a good choice for a column name (you would need to surround it with backticks everytime you use it, which is error-prone)